# Viewing a feed of questions with favourite tags from multiple SE sites?

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

Is there a way for me to view a feed of questions that have my favourite tags across multiple SE sites?

For example, I have the VHDL tag favourited at StackOverflow, Electronic Engineering & Code Review and guitar favourited at Music.  it possible to view a feed of questions with these tags at once, instead of manually going through each one and scrolling for highlighted posts?

It would be great to have a personalised feed, especially to allow for participation on sites where there isn't enough activity on certain tags to justify checking in every day on multiple sites.

Comment: I've never used it but does the following do what you're after: http://stackexchange.com/filters/

Comment: @PeterJ is correct, there is a built in filter called "Favorite Tags" with a description "View questions based on your favorite tags across the Stack Exchange network" - Peter, you can post this as answer.

Comment: I keep looking for my filters in the iPhone app. Maybe someday they'll be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the main [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) page you can find a variety of interesting things that relate to the overall network. Under the [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) tab you'll find an option that allows you to follow questions based on a particular tag across all sites or a subset of sites.

Also as [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) mentioned in a comment there is a built in filter called "Favorite Tags" that allows you to view questions based on your favorite tags across the Stack Exchange network.